# how can i make scroll smooth this my navbar code

Tags: reactjs

Expected behavior:

Whenever I click the section in the Navbar, I want to go to there immediately, without any animation.

```
import React from 'react';

function Navbar() {
    const scrollToSection = (id) => {
        const element = document.getElementById(id);
        if (element) {
            element.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth',
                block: 'start',
            });
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className='navbar'>
            <ul className='item8'>
                <li className='item01'>
                    <a onClick={() => scrollToSection('hero')} className='op' href="#home">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li className='item01'>
                    <a onClick={() => scrollToSection('about')} className='op' href="#about">ABOUT ME</a>
                </li>
                <li className='item01'>
                    <a onClick={() => scrollToSection('contact')} className='op' href="#contact">CONTACT ME</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

I have reviewed my code, but I can't seem to figure out why this error is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The smooth scrolling effect in your present implementation is achieved by using `scrollIntoView` with the behavior set to 'smooth'. You may easily remove the `behavior:'smooth'` attribute from the `scrollIntoView` options if you wish to navigate right away without the smooth scroll animation.

Updated code:

```
import React from 'react';

function Navbar() {
    const scrollToSection = (id) => {
        const element = document.getElementById(id);
        if (element) {
            element.scrollIntoView({
                block: 'start', // Scroll to the top of the element
                inline: 'nearest', // Scroll to the nearest edge of the element
            });
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className='navbar'>
            <ul className='item8'>
                <li className='item01'>
                    <a onClick={() => scrollToSection('hero')} className='op' href="#home">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li className='item01'>
                    <a onClick={() => scrollToSection('about')} className='op' href="#about">ABOUT ME</a>
                </li>
                <li className='item01'>
                    <a onClick={() => scrollToSection('contact')} className='op' href="#contact">CONTACT ME</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

The `scrollIntoView` settings can be modified to eliminate the `behavior:'smooth'` property, which will cause the scroll to occur instantly without the smooth animation effect. The addition of the `block:'start'` and `inline: 'nearest'` properties guarantees that the element scrolls to the top and nearest edge, respectively. Modify these attributes according to your unique scrolling needs.